# Can Android apps be native and Java

Tags: java, android, c++, decompiler

I was just wondering if Android apps can be made from a combination of native (C++) and Java code. This is because I tried decompiling an Android app (just to see how hard it is) and I got quite a bit of Java code, but some of the methods/functions that I recon would do very important and secure work simply return null in the Java code. I guess that they actually reference a C++ library and that the decompiler does not understand that, could this be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **NDK** is the solution to all Android problems :)

I noted with interest that all the best performing games I have are all written in the NDK (get Addons Detector - used mainly for seeing which app contains those ** push advert APIs, but it also tells you which dev tools were used for an app).

Writing with the NDK means you won't have any worries about using the C++ library. If you want to keep your Java code, you can just use JNI to call it, or wrap it in a class.

Courtesy : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213172/developing-an-android-app-that-include-a-c-toolkit

Comment: Thanks, but do you think the use of JNI would result in this decompiler behavior or should I expect to see something more?

Comment: Depends on the decompiler.  I would imagine most would mark the method as native and declare it without a body.  That's what Procyon does.